# Discord.js roles overlapping

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am making a discord bot, with discord.js. Everything works, fine. (ignore the messy code, i am not great). So basically, to access certain commands, you have to have a certain role. You change which role has those commands by doing, !change (role ID). It works fine in one server, but when i add the bot to 2 servers, i messes everything up, because when I want to have one (Role ID) be for one server, and another (Role ID) be for another server.

So the 2+ servers are always competing for which role is going to work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json')
var Admin = '733382542631239749';


var prefix = "!";
var blank = 0
//COMMANDS

//1.Logging in for console
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
 });

client.on('message', message =>{
  var args = message.content.slice(blank.length).split(" ");
  switch(args[0]) {
    //STAFF COMMANDS
    //STAFF COMMANDS
    //Utility/Moderation
    //clear


    case (prefix + 'change') || message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'):

          if (args[1]) {
            Admin = (args[1])
            console.log(Admin)
          }

    break;
    case (prefix + 'clear'):

    
      if (args[1])
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.get(Admin)){
          message.delete(); 
          message.reply('You dont have the roles. Please contact the admin of the server if you think this is a mistake.')
          return;
        }else{
          message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1])
          console.log(message.member.user.username + message.content)
        }
        
        break;
    case (prefix + 'log'):
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.get(Admin)){
        message.delete(); 
        message.reply('You dont have the roles. Please contact the admin of the server if you think this is a mistake.')
        return;
      }else{
        console.log(client.users)
      }
      
    break;
    case (prefix + 'uptime'):
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.get(Admin)){
        message.delete(); 
        message.reply('You dont have the roles. Please contact the admin of the server if you think this is a mistake.')
        return;
      }else{
        message.channel.send(client.uptime * 0.001)
      }
        
      break;

    //Kick
    case (prefix + 'kick'):
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.get(Admin)){
        message.delete(); 
        message.reply('You dont have the roles. Please contact the admin of the server if you think this is a mistake.')
        return;
      }else{
        const user = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (args[1]){
          if (user) {
            const member = message.guild.member(user)
            if (member) {
              member
              .kick('Reason')
              .then(() => {
                message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
              })
            }
          }
        }
      }
        
      break;
      //Ban


      case (prefix + 'ban'):

        if (!message.member.roles.cache.get(Admin)){
          message.delete(); 
          message.reply('You dont have the roles. Please contact the admin of the server if you think this is a mistake.')
          return;
        }else{
          const user1 = message.mentions.users.first()
          if (args[1]){
            if (user1) {
              const member1 = message.guild.member(user1)
              if (member1) {
                member1
                .ban('Reason')
                .then(() => {
                  message.reply(`Successfully banned ${user.tag}`);
                })
              }
            }
          }
        }
        break;
        //FUN COMMANDS

        //GIFS
        //Rip
        case (prefix + 'rip'):
          const attachmentRip = new MessageAttachment('https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohzdYrOxm6awk0HDy/giphy.gif');
          message.channel.send(attachmentRip);
          break;
        case (prefix + 'kill'):
          const attachmentKill = new MessageAttachment('https://media.giphy.com/media/KPTgXXjURfR4s/giphy.gif')
          message.channel.send(attachmentKill)
        break;

        case (prefix + 'lol'):
          const attachmentLol = new MessageAttachment('https://media.giphy.com/media/83YPtFOmc9x3a/giphy.gif')
          message.channel.send(attachmentLol);
        break;

        case (prefix + 'ping'):
            message.channel.send('Pong')
        break;

        










        //HELP

        case (prefix + 'help'):
          message.channel.send('Go to www.WeDontHaveAWebsite.com' + ' ' + 'for more info!')

        break;



    default:
      // code block
      return;
  }
})



client.login(config.token);
```

As i said, all i want is so i can have my bot on multiple servers at the same time.

Comment: Your problem is the your bot is sharing state between the servers it is connected to. You should redesign your code so that for each server you connect to, you have a distinct state containing role and so on.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If the bot is running in multiple guilds, just switch on the guild ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bot to be "mutliserver-proof", you have to use some sort of database. I would suggest using [Enmap](http://enmap.evie.dev/), which is a simple js to sqlite database designed to work perfectly with discord.js.
You just have to store the role id with its guild id somehow.
The change command should update the value stored in the database for the guild the command is executed in.

It would look something like:

```
case (prefix + 'change') || message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'):

         if (args[1]) {
            yourDatabase.set('admin', args[1], message.guild.id)
            console.log(yourDatabase.get('admin', message.guild.id)
      }

break;
```

This is the syntax used by Enmap ^-^. Check out the link I gave above to get more information about Enmap methods.
In the given example, you can access the role id with `yourDatabase.get('admin', message.guild.id)`.

Comment: I dont fully understand. Is there a way u could tell me step by step? If you are willing to, here is a blank discord server. https://discord.gg/D5M3ktm